# Psychometric information on IPIP representation of NEO facets

Tags: reference-request, measurement, personality

The IPIP (International Personality Item Pool) website provides a [copy of the IPIP representation of the NEO 30 facet form](http://ipip.ori.org/newNEOFacetsKey.htm).

It also provides some information [comparing IPIP NEO with official NEO](http://ipip.ori.org/newNEO_FacetsTable.htm).
However, the information provided is incomplete for making an assessment of the psychometric properties of the test. For example, I'd like to know about: (a) how items were chosen; (b) what was the sample size and characteristics used to generate the comparative correlation information provided; and (c) what is the factor structure of the IPIP NEO.

Thus, my questions:

- Where can I find information on how the IPIP NEO (30 facet version) was developed?
- What studies have examined the psychometric properties of the IPIP NEO (30 facet version) both in absolute terms and relative to the official NEO?

Comment: Did you asked the author(s)? I also tried to mimic official NEO-PI with IPIP but also couldnt find norms. I asked on faculty but they told me that norms does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

The table found at your second link (comparing the IPIP NEO and official NEO) seems to have come from this paper by Goldberg (1999): http://projects.ori.org/lrg/PDFs_papers/A%20broad-bandwidth%20inventory.pdf. This paper discusses the generation of the IPIP items as well as the sample it was originally administered in. A 2006 paper (also by Goldberg) provides additional information on IPIP development:

Unfortunately, I was unable to locate information on the factor structure of the IPIP NEO 30 facet form, only the IPIP 50-item FFM (Ehrhart, Roesch, Ehrhart, & Kilian, 2008), which seems to be a different measure (http://ipip.ori.org/newFinding_Labeling_IPIP_Scales.htm).

Ehrhart, K. H., Roesch, S. C., Ehrhart, M. G., & Kilian, B. (2008). A test of the factor structure equivalence of the 50-Item IPIP Five-Factor Model Measure across gender and ethnic groups. *Journal of Personality Assessment, 90*(5), 507–516.

Goldberg, L. A., Johnson, J. A., Hogan, R. , Ashton, M. C., Cloninger, & Gough, H. G. (2006). The international personality item pool and the future of public-domain personality measures. *Journal of Research in Personality, 40*, 84–96.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old, but it is still relevant so I will attempt to answer.

In the meantime Johnson has developed a 120-item version of the IPIP-NEO. The development is described in detail here:

Johnson, J. A. (2014). Measuring thirty facets of the Five Factor Model with a 120-item public domain inventory: Development of the IPIP-NEO-120. Journal of Research in Personality, 51, 78–89. https://doi.org/10/bc99

And there is an additional validation study here:

Kajonius, P. J., & Johnson, J. A. (2019). Assessing the Structure of the Five Factor Model of Personality (IPIP-NEO-120) in the Public Domain. Europe’s Journal of Psychology, 15(2), 260–275. https://doi.org/10/gh8gk3

I can definitely recommend reading both papers. While the IPIP-NEO-120 has some psychometric problems, the NEO-PI-R is also far from perfect. I believe IPIP is the future due to its non-proprietary nature.